# Docker doesn't map files

Tags: docker

I'm trying to use Docker. Process https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/ step by step. Step "Create a Django project" passed successfully except of point 3. New files are created in container, but not in host filesystem. What I missed?

Run on Windows 10 Home, Docker 18.03.0.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, you need to mount the container volume to your host to be able to get synchronization between container files and project folder on your host.

To mount the volume you can keep going with the doc, it's in step 9 when you create the docker-compose file :

```
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

More info about volume and docker here : https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: Yes, I made docker-compose.yml exactly as in the guide. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you've created the docker-compose.yml file as described in the guide, and still do not see the files, then one of two things come to mind:

1. Inside the container you are creating files somewhere other than the volume directory. You can check inside your container with (get the value of `$container_id` from `docker ps`):

`docker exec -it $container_id ls -l /code`

2. On your host, your current directory isn't shared with the Linux VM (since you are running on Windows). Go into the docker settings (should be an icon in your toolbar) and check the shared drives and folders. Note the case of any file and directory names since Linux is case sensitive.

Comment: 1. I checked files in container, and they are on the right place, into /code
2. I see "Docker quickstart terminal", but no any settings. Maybe it's because of windows 10 home, not professional?